# Execut file in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

That's not a typo in the title. There is an `execut` file (no 'e') in my main bin/Debug folder, and I don't know what it's for. Is it necessary to distribute the solution?

Comment: I can't find what you're referring to. What version of Visual Studio are you using? Can you post a screenshot showing that file?

Comment: The name of the file is Program.execut

Comment: Is this an executable file that you built yourself?  Or was built for you by `Visual Studio`?  It sounds to me like a typo on your end.

Comment: What is the Project type?

Comment: @Brian Apparently it was built by Visual Studio. I did delete the file and it didn't coma back. Thanks.

Comment: @Vitaliy Desktop application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds to me like an artefact of the compilation, or something created by the program itself.

Is this your own code ?

If you delete the file and rebuild, does it come back ?

If you choose the Clean solution option in Visual studio does it go away ?

Lastly, you can always copy the contents of the debug folder to another location on your HDD and then remove this file. If the program still operates then you don't need to distribute it with your solution.

Comment: Thanks. Not my own code. When clean solution the file doesn't go away. I did delete the file. When build the solution the file doesn't come back. The program works fine without the file. Weird.